# How to solve 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient' assembly error? SSIS: Can not run data mining query task

Tags: ssis, adomd

I am trying to run data mining query task in SSIS project in visual studio. Analysis service instance is running on azure cloud. I am trying to execute mdx query to retrieve data from AAS.

Connection to Azure Analysis Service is set up via `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Service 14.0`.

When task is executed, following error occurs:

```
Error: 0x0 at Data Mining Query Task: Failed to execute data mining query due to the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Task failed: Data Mining Query Task
```

As per error description, I installed ADOMD drivers from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-data-providers

How can I get past this error? Despite of installing ADOMD drives, Am I missing something regarding assembly it is trying to find?

Comment: It sounds like you need to install AMO and MSOLAP as well based on the comment in that link: _Azure Analysis Services requires the latest versions of all three libraries_

Comment: I installed both AMO and MSOLAP. All are latest version, still same error. One thing I noticed is that error shows assembly v14 is missing. Installed ADOMD version is 15.x.x. That might be a reason. I tried to find older version of it with no success.

Comment: Try updating the connection manager with the new versions you installed